# Quartz Crone Scheduler end time

Tags: java, cron

I'm trying to make this trigger run every 3 minutes between 8:15 and 9:45. Is there a possible cron expression that could achive that? If not, can there be more schedules for one trigger or do I just need more triggers?

```
        String startDateStr = "2017-10-01 00:00:00.0";
        String endDateStr = "2018-06-30 00:00:00.0";

        Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(startDateStr);
        Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(endDateStr);

        CronTrigger lesson1 = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("lesson1", "Lessons")
                .startAt(startDate)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 15/3 8 * * ? *").withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .endAt(endDate)
                .forJob("Lesson1", "Lessons")
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
0 15-45/3 8 * * ?
```

**EDIT:**

What about this one:

```
0 15-45/3 8-9 * * ?
```

Comment: This stops after 8:45, I need it to go to 9:45, right now I'm trying to solve it with more triggers which seems to work, but it doesnt look "pretty"

Comment: Added another suggestion: `0 15-45/3 8-9 * * ?`

Comment: This skips 8:45-9:15 which also has to included

Comment: Then it's not different from `0 15-45/3 8,9 * * ?`?

Comment: Yes, its the same

Comment: Hmm can't think of any other solution that doesn't involve two separate cron jobs, unfortunately.